# Decorate except blocks without any change

Tags: python, decorator

Existing code contains lots of `except` blocks, which suppress exceptions.

```
def div(x, y):
    result = None
    try:
        result = x / y
    except:
        pass
    return result


print div(5,0)
```

I want to decorate `except` blocks in order to print the exceptions without changing the original code. Is this possible in Python?

Comment: show us your real code snippet to see an example.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible.

In Python only objects may be decorated.

Try/except block is one of [compound statements](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement). Statements cannot be used as arguments - therefore you cannot write such a decorator.

Moreover, if exception is silenced, decorator (or any other code outside of statement) will have no knowledge about a fact that an exception was raised.